# How to limit the scope of ancestor search in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Example input:

```
<body>
  <ul>
     <li>
       <p>Some text with <b><i><span style="color:red">formatting</span></i></b></p>
   </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

The 'inline' elements are `b`, `i`, or `span`

Suppose the context node is the nested `span` element in the example.

How do I get all ancestor inline elements, without the search going past the containing `p` element?

The expression `ancestor-or-self::*[self::b | self::i | self::span]` should actually work, as there can't be ancestor inline elements containing 'block' level elements such as `p`, `ul`, etc.

But, I wonder if there is some performance cost that could be avoided, as I think the search will continue past the containing `p` element.  Is there a way to avoid that?

**Edit**

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
<xsl:function name="my:getInlineSeq" as="element() *">
    <xsl:param name="pElem" as="element()" />
    <xsl:if test="$pElem[self::b | self::i | self::span]">
        <xsl:sequence select="my:getInlineSeq($pElem/parent::*)" />
        <xsl:sequence select="$pElem" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:function>
```

But, I'm unsure if there is an better or 'standard' way of solving this problem.

Note: the `$pElem/parent::*` in the code will always return an element as inline items must have a block element container such as `p`, `h1`, etc.  Also, the assumption is the `$pElem` parameter provided initially is always an inline element.

Comment: Do you always have/expect an `ancestor::p` element?

Comment: @MartinHonnen no, it could also be `h1`, `h2`, .., `h6`, or `li`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using

```
<xsl:function name="mf:block" as="element()">
    <xsl:param name="inline" as="element()"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="$inline/ancestor::*[self::h1 | self::h2 | self::h3 | self::h4 | self::h5 | self::h6 | self::li | self::p][1]"/>
</xsl:function>
```

and your assumption about block and inline elements you could rewrite `ancestor-or-self::*[self::b | self::i | self::span]` in the context of `match="span | b | i"` to

```
for $block in mf:block(.) return ancestor-or-self::*[. >> $block]
```

I think (or assuming you use `<xsl:variable name="block" select="mf:block(.)"/>` to `ancestor-or-self::*[. >> $block]`. I have no idea whether that performs any better than your attempt.

Tried to test the expression at http://xsltransform.net/3MvmrzK where

```
<xsl:template match="span | b | i">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="inline-ancestor" select="ancestor-or-self::*[self::b | self::i | self::span]/name()"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="test-block" select="for $block in mf:block(.) return ancestor-or-self::*[. >> $block]/name()"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

gives the same result for the inline elements with

```
   <p>Some text with <b inline-ancestor="b" test-block="b"><i inline-ancestor="b i" test-block="b i"><span style="color:red" inline-ancestor="b i span" test-block="b i span">formatting</span></i></b></p>
```